# Real-time video stabilization

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camera

I got a Google Pixel and tried recording a video with the official app, I found out there is a remarkable built-in stabilization mechanism happening on the recording, so if I shake my hand a bit this movement is only slightly transferred to the recording (even the video preview is impressively stable).

However I tried with my own Video recording app and this stabilization is not happening.

I of course tried with the `setVideoStabilization()` method over at [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) but the result is not as good as with the builtin Camera app.

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: _"Is there anything else I am missing?"_ Yes it's called a multi-million dollar R&D budget + some bad-ass Patents ownership to outclass the current competition... Seriously though, you have to **code your own stabilization** algorithm for the recorded pixels (since no access to re-program the camera's imaging sensor itself). Here is some inspirational [**search results**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Video+Stabilization+algorithm). Basically just **consider the concepts** presented and have fun implementing into Java code...

Comment: It's more than likely that the stabilization code used by the Google app is *not* the same stabilization library that is available to us mere mortal developers.

Comment: @VC.One sorry, are really meaning **code you own stabilization** on Java/Kotlin level? Do you even understand what are talking about? It has to be happening with low-level programming language (somewhere at camera low-level system logic, which is not exposed to Android app developers), only this way it can be done fast and effective (won't affect performance). Seriously... :) You can write your own algorithm if you have a Arduino, Raspberry Pi, Mini PC and so on. You have Linux and you can do everything you want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider looking at [OpenSource.Android](http://source.android.com/source/) and find some logic for stabilization. Another link is here [platform_packages_apps_camera](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera). From there onwards you can do your own R&D.

Or

Wait until a Google Pixel Camera stabilization based API, or such code, is available to everyone. 
A future update to the Android SDK may improve upon the current stabilization feature.

Comment: In that Platform Package for Camera, this [**`dbstabsmooth.cpp`**](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/33c59af04ab44eff0e3806f140d472252300646a/jni/feature_stab/src/dbreg/dbstabsmooth.cpp) looks most promising for logic inspiration, or as starting point to Asker's own implementation.

Comment: @Qamar relax man, I just thought maybe I was doing something wrong since there *is* some support for stabilization on the current Camera API

Comment: @MichelReap it's not personal... The Answer has to also speak to future readers needing this same info.

Comment: @both to be honest I thought this stabilization process took place in the hardware itself. I am using Android phones to live broadcast and adding software stabilization would most likely impact my encoding performance and reduce the stable, clean 30fps with 1080p I get now... Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: you can't easily do your own stabilization algorithm for general Google Play apps and official Android firmwares https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102904/real-time-video-stabilization#comment122682031_41102904

Answer (score 0):

Wait for Google to release it in their API.

From previous experience new features generally take a little while to get through for us all to use in API form.

In the meantime try and get the attention of the experts here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list. You may get it pushed into an update earlier even

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait, an alternative is to read [this amazing article on content unshaking using the accelerometer](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/no-shake-screen-stabilization-android) (with [sourcecode here](https://github.com/ryanchyshyn/aosp_screen_stabilization/tree/system_svc)).

This was done to unshake the phone's content (to ease reading in moving transport for example), but it's the same logic you can apply to video feeds from the camera.

However, don't expect to get the same results as Google's approach. Indeed, this can only do software stabilization, which will move around your image, and thus crop it. To avoid cropping and luminance change, Google's uses [Optical Image Stabilization, which mechanically moves the lens](http://www.androidauthority.com/ois-optical-image-stabilization-explained-677976/), and thus avoids any cropping. However, OIS is not yet supported on all phones, so take this into account if you use Google's API in your app.